# Perl, Pattern Matching each element ($line) in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, design-patterns, matching

I have a simple enough problem I think, I have recently ran a script which extracted specific information from the string in each element in an array. I have written this before and it functions well however when trying the very simple version of it right now it will not presen data only the same response uninitialized value argument! I am getting really frustrated as my previous code works. I am clearly doing something STUPID and would love some help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my@histone;
my$line;
my$idea;
my$file="demo_site.txt";

open(IN, "<$file")||die"\ncannot be opend\n";

@histone=<IN>;
print @histone;

foreach $line(@histone)
       {
           $line=~ m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t/;

           print$1."\n";
           print$2."\n";
           print$3."\n";

       }
```

The infile "demo_site.txt" takes the format of a tab delimited .txt file:

```
chr9        1234       5678     .     200      .      14.0      -1
```

This file has multiple lines as above and I wish to extract the first three items of data so the output looks as follows.

```
chr9
1234
5678
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume, that `file.txt` have what you want: (`file.txt eq demo_site.txt` )

```
chr9        1234       5678     .     200      .      14.0      -1
```

you can use simple thing:

```
perl -ane '$" = "\n"; print "@F[0..2]"' file.txt 1>output.txt
```

One-liners in Perl are powerful. And you don't need to write your scripts for simple tasks;)

Just open Terminal sometimes;)

P.S:

This is not very good one-liner, I know, but It do what It must.

Comment: That is really close to the output that I need! Who cares what it looks like when it does the job I suppose ;)

Comment: I understand that my coding is quite rigid but I am really surprised that this does not work as I have another script that this works no problem at all that i wrote yesterday and runs even now...  Why it does not work with the much simpler straight forward code is beyond me!

Comment: More than that! I think, that if I done some annoying work with one-liner (sometimes one-liners are more simple than scipts), I need to open another script and input one-liner into `qx()`

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a regular expression since it's tab delimited.

```
foreach $line(@histone)
       {
           @line_data = split(/\t/,$line)

           print $line_data[0]."\n";
           print $line_data[1]."\n";
           print $line_data[2]."\n";

       }
```

Edit:
If you want to assign the values to specific named variables, assign it in a temporary array.

```
($varA, $varB, $varC .... ) = split(/\t/,$line)
```

Comment: That is true however for further use I would like to be able to assign each of the data points to a variable to be used as input for code later on.

Comment: I added an example showing how you could do that using split.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem here is that you're trying to print the values of `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, but you only have one set of capturing parenthesis in your regex, so only `$1` gets a value. `$2` and `$3` will remain undefined and hence give you that error when you try to print them.

The solution is to add two more sets of capturing parenthesis. I expect you want something like this:

```
$line=~ m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\t([0-9]+)\t([0-9]+)\t/;
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to add that as an edit to mine, you ninja-ed me!

Answer (score 0):

$line=~ m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t/)

First of all, the parens are not balanced.

Second, I haven't checked this, but don't you need a set of parens for each capture?

Third, as misplacedme said split() is definitely the way to go. ;)

Comment: sorry the unbalanced parens is due to me messing with the code so much I left in a final ")" at the end that should not be there

Comment: Ok I have seen all of your recommendations are really good and work so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I may self-promote, you can use [Tie::Array::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) to give direct read-write access to the file as a Perl array of arrayrefs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::Array::CSV;
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'demo_site.txt', sep_char => "\t";

print $file[0][0]; # first line before first tab
$file[2][1] = 10; # set the third line between the first and second tabs
```